# How to find application scripts in node inspector faster?

Tags: node.js, express

While watching node-inspector screencasts I noticed app scripts on top of scripts list and they contains full path.

But when I using it - all scripts are shuffled with system scipts and it very hard to find ones that relates only to my app.

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You don't do anything wrong, the code has just evolved between the screencasts and now...

To re-enable the full path files visible you could apply the following :

At the line 192 in the file node-inspector/lib/session.js you will find this function call :

```
scripts.forEach(function(s) {
  var hidden = config.hidden &&
               config.hidden.some(function(r) { return r.test(s.url); }),
      item = { hidden: hidden, path: s.url };
  if (s.path.length > 1) s.url = shorten(s.path);
  item.url = s.url;
  sourceIDs[s.sourceID] = item;
  delete s.path;
  if (!hidden) {
    sendEvent('parsedScriptSource', s);
  }
});
```

To have the full path of the file in the debugger just remove the line where the url is shortened like this :

```
//if (s.path.length > 1) s.url = shorten(s.path);
```

This will do the job even if not an optimal solution.

PS : you will find the source of this file here : https://github.com/dannycoates/node-inspector/blob/master/lib/session.js